# keras gives error when using two loss function for two outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I have a network. the one before last layer is a dense layer. I want the last layer to return both the max value from the layer before, and the index of that max value.

so if the output of the dense layer is [0,4,5,120,1], the last layer should return [120, 3].
the loss I need the network to work with is calculated only based on the max value, not the index. therefore, I wrote a loss function for the second output, the index, that always returns zero - but if there is a better solution I would like to hear it, in addition to how to fix this error.

the code is:

```
def ignor_loss(preds, trues):
    return 0

# build deep q network
inputs = Input((240,256,3))
pool0 = MaxPooling2D()(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(30,3,activation='relu')(pool0)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D()(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(40,3,activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D()(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(50,3,activation='relu')(pool2)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D()(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(60,3,activation='relu')(pool3)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D()(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(80,3,activation='relu')(pool4)
flat = Flatten()(conv5)
dense1 = Dense(70)(flat)
dense2 = Dense(40)(dense1)
values = Dense(env.action_space.n)(dense2)
max_, ind = Lambda(lambda x : [K.max(x),K.argmax(x)])(values)
m = Model(inputs, [max_, ind])
m.compile('adam', ['mse',ignor_loss])
```

and the error is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

any ideas?

**EDIT:**

here is my updated code:

```
# build deep q network
inputs = Input((240,256,3))
pool0 = MaxPooling2D()(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(30,3,activation='relu')(pool0)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D()(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(40,3,activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D()(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(50,3,activation='relu')(pool2)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D()(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(60,3,activation='relu')(pool3)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D()(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(80,3,activation='relu')(pool4)
flat = Flatten()(conv5)
dense1 = Dense(70)(flat)
dense2 = Dense(40)(dense1)
q_values = Dense(env.action_space.n)(dense2)
max_q =  Lambda(lambda x : K.max(x), name='max')(q_values)
ind = Lambda(lambda x : K.argmax(x), name='ind')(q_values)
m = Model(inputs, [max_q,ind])
m.compile('adam', {'max':'mse','ind':'mse'}, loss_weights=[1., 0.0])
```

I still get the same error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I need to know why this error heppens? any ideas?

**EDIT 2:**
now I added the `keepdims=True` to the max function and `K.expand_dims` to the argmax func, like this:

```
q_values = Dense(env.action_space.n)(dense2)
max_q =  Lambda(lambda x : K.max(x, keepdims=True), name='max')(q_values)
ind = Lambda(lambda x : K.expand_dims(K.argmax(x)), name='ind')(q_values)
m = Model(inputs, [max_q,ind])
m.compile('adam', {'max':'mse','ind':'mse'}, loss_weights=[1., 0.0])
```

but I get a different error:

```
TypeError: Expected int64, got 0.0 of type 'float' instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is a cleaner solution

1 step: fit the model on the max

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (2,240,256,3))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, 2)

inputs = Input((240,256,3))
pool0 = MaxPooling2D()(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(30,3,activation='relu')(pool0)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D()(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(40,3,activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D()(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(50,3,activation='relu')(pool2)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D()(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(60,3,activation='relu')(pool3)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D()(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(80,3,activation='relu')(pool4)
flat = Flatten()(conv5)
dense1 = Dense(70)(flat)
dense2 = Dense(40)(dense1)
values = Dense(10)(dense2) # in my case env.action_space.n is 10
max_ = Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True))(values)

m = Model(inputs, max_)
m.compile('adam', 'mse')
m.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

2 step: make inference with the fitted model returning max and argmax (this simply require to build a new model)

```
ind = Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.argmax(x, axis=1),-1))(values)
final_model = Model(inputs, [max_, ind])
final_model.predict(X) this return max and argmax
```

**EDIT**: here a compact model which operate all the operation. if u have two outputs u need to pass to keras two targets. for this reason, the second target is generated by me as an array of 0 (it has no impact)

```
def ignor_loss(trues, preds):
    return 0.

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (2,240,256,3))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, 2)

inputs = Input((240,256,3))
pool0 = MaxPooling2D()(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(30,3,activation='relu')(pool0)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D()(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(40,3,activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D()(conv2)
conv3 = Conv2D(50,3,activation='relu')(pool2)
pool3 = MaxPooling2D()(conv3)
conv4 = Conv2D(60,3,activation='relu')(pool3)
pool4 = MaxPooling2D()(conv4)
conv5 = Conv2D(80,3,activation='relu')(pool4)
flat = Flatten()(conv5)
dense1 = Dense(70)(flat)
dense2 = Dense(40)(dense1)
values = Dense(10)(dense2) # in my case env.action_space.n is 10
max_ = Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True), name='max')(values)
ind = Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.argmax(x, axis=1),-1), name='ind')(values)

m = Model(inputs, [max_,ind])
m.compile('adam', loss={'max':'mse', 'ind':ignor_loss}, 
      loss_weights={'max':1., 'ind':0.})
m.fit(X, {'max':y, 'ind':np.zeros_like(y)}, epochs=3)
m.predict(X)
```

Comment: ty, but I'am aware of this solution. I am interested in knowing how to build a model with two outputs and apply loss to only one. and regardless, knowing why my current solution is not working.

Comment: In general, I skeptical about the approach of max and argmax function... however, two output/loss required 2 target... do u have 2 targets in order to apply this kind of fit?

Comment: not sure what you mean by target, but i need the max value to be a certain value - that is, i have a true y for it - and the index is somthing I need for a different purpose, I dont want the network to train on it

Comment: I added the example with two outputs and apply loss to only one... don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer ;-)

Comment: thanks, but I want to build the model using keras, not tensorflow...also, why use reduce_max instead of just tf.max? also, why do you need to expand dims when getting the max ind?

Comment: this is Keras, and this operation are what you need, they are also accessible in tensorflow.keras.backend (K)... keepdims/expand_dim are useful to maintain the 2D dimensionality (n_batch, features), with K.max(keepdims=True) and K.expand_dims() is the same. don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer ;-)

Comment: I will, but my code still dosent work and I dont know y. look at my edit please.also, I dont know why you used reduce max instead of just max?

Comment: Here the working example https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IKiSWXUVfz2hIJINvFKHcJx6BCv6NP8x?usp=sharing  reduce_max and max are the same you only have to take care of diemsionality. don't forget to upvote and accept it as answer ;-)

Comment: I appriciate the effort, my friend, but I can only accept an answer that tells me how to fix my own code (look at the edit), what coused the problem and why the fix is fixing it :)

Comment: my friend, in the link I used and fixed your exact code (look at it). the error is caused because u don't handle properly the dimension. you have to use keepdim and expandim because with your operation you are destroying the batch dimensionality which is required by keras

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216767/discussion-between---and-marco-cerliani).